# Brand new HDD acts very slow

Tags: windows, hard-drive

SMART data shows nothing wrong. I just bought the drive. It is a 500GB HDD from SEAGATE with 16MB chache 7200RPM.

I have a fresh install of Windows with a few applications, nothing major. Yet, coming out of sleep mode can take over a minute just for me to bring up an RDP window.

From Task Manager, I can see the drive hitting 100% usage at around 10MB/s.

Is this normal for a new drive? What could cause this or how can I figure out what is wrong?

Could this be a bad SATA cable?

Comment: Are the drivers for the motherboard properly installed?  Have you tried HDD benchmarking software and compare with typical results?

Comment: I was wondering what version of Windows, and Model of hard drive. Also, how much RAM does the machine have, because if sleep mode actually shutdown the hardware, you are basically doing an awake from hibernate. If you have a lot of RAM, it has to load it all in. If you had a bad or under rated cable (SATA1, vice what you need), all disk access would be slow (e.g. transferring large files to/from the disk).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things which could be causing this:

1. Are your chipset drivers correctly installed?  May be worth a reinstall.
2. Does the drive have up to date firmware?  It could be that if the drives firmware is outdated - this has been fixed in a later revision.
3. Have you tried replacing the SATA cable?  Although unlikely, a worse quality cable can affect performance.

Further to this - it may be worth running HDD benchmarking software to see if the drive is actually underperforming or whether your computer is actually being over-worked and is not pulling big amounts of data from the drive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you upgrade firmware for a harddrive? 
How can I find the motherboard model to know what drivers to isntall?

Comment: to upgrade the hard drive firmware, get the model number off the drive, go to the manufacturers website and look at their firmware, drivers and downloads section.  They should be packaged as a normal installer.  Same for motherboard, however if you have a "big brand pc" (dell, hp etc) you can go to their site and search by pc model number